# IntelliJ Idea - Jump to test code of covered code?

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, code-coverage

Is there a way to jump to test code that is already in place? for example, let's say I have a method and some of the code is 'covered' after I run with coverage. How would I be able to tell what unit tests are covering this code without manually checking each test?

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-code-coverage-results.html#junit

Answer (score 2):

@jonrsharpe gave me the resources to answer this question, so thanks!
check this out here, it will give you all the information you will need: [info on viewing code coverage results](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-code-coverage-results.html#junit)

this feature can be accessed by clicking on the coloured line by your code and clicking on a button called 'show tests covering line' this option is only available if you enable 'tracing' for your code coverage. this option can be enabled from configuring the test task. info on this bit here: [info on configuring run profiles for code coverage](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-application.html#codeCoverageTab)

Comment: This is out of date. The current way to set up tracing is in this link in the IntelliJ documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-test-with-coverage.html#coverage-run-configurations